# Unexpected "compound assignment not allowed with nullable operands" compilation error

Tags: ballerina

In the code below I have correctly narrowed the type of `str` to `string`. However the second `+=` compound operator gives me a compilation error:

```
ERROR compound assignment not allowed with nullable operands
ERROR operator '+' not defined for 'string?' and 'string'
```

It looks like the compiler unexpectedly doesn't obey the type narrowing anymore?  I'm expecting the type of `str` to be `string` until end of the block and I fail to see any problems in my code.

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    string? str = "a";
    if str is string {
        str += "b";
        
        // why the second append fails ?
        // ERROR compound assignment not allowed with nullable operands
        // ERROR operator '+' not defined for 'string?' and 'string'
        // str += "c";

        // one possible workaround
        str = <string>str + "c";
    }
    io:println(str);
}
```

I'm using:

```
$ bal version
Ballerina 2201.1.0 (Swan Lake Update 1)
Language specification 2022R2
Update Tool 1.3.9
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because type narrowing no longer applies once there is a possibility that the variable may have been assigned to.

For example, it is possible to assign `()` to `str`, but thereafter `str` cannot be of the narrowed type.

```
    string? str = "a";
    if str is string {
        str = ();

        // Now not valid, `str` is no longer `string`.
        str += "c";
    }
```

There was a [discussion](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/842) on whether it would be possible to continue to narrow the type if the assignment is with a value belonging to the narrowed type, such as that in the original example. But at the time it was decided not to do this due to reasons discussed in [the spec issue](https://github.com/ballerina-platform/ballerina-spec/issues/842#issuecomment-887164579).

Comment: Ok, I see now. However I'm a bit surprised because I didn't see how `a += "b"` could ever change the type of `a`. Unfortunately I again fail to find any documentation about this detail. In the actual code I think I'm going to hide the unavoidable type test jungle into a function :)

Comment: The ballerina specification explains this. "A narrowed type for a variable x implied by an expression in which x occurs ceases to apply in a region of code where there is a possibility at runtime that x has been assigned to since the evaluation of the expression. It is an error if this results in the type of a variable reference being affected by assignments that lexically follow the variable reference." under conditional type narrowing (https://ballerina.io/spec/lang/2022R2/#conditional_variable_type_narrowing)